Quartz.NET job is not executing Windows Service C#
I am creating a Windows service in C#. I'm trying to set up a service schedule using a library Quartz.NET. I encountered a problem - Job does not fire according to the schedule. The program simply does not enter the method Execute. That is, after the next section of code, nothing happens.
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
           try
                                {
                                    ISchedulerFactory schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
                                    Task.Run(async () =>
                                    {
                                        IScheduler scheduler = await schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();
                                        await scheduler.Start();
                                        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<CronJob>().WithIdentity("CronJob", "DefaultGroup").Build();
                                        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                                                                         .WithIdentity("Trigger", "DefaultGroup")
                                                                         .StartNow()
                                                                         .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                                                                                                    .WithIntervalInSeconds(30).RepeatForever()).Build();
                                                                        
                                                                         
                                        await scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
                                    }).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                                }
                                catch(Exception ex)
                                {
                                    ServiceLogger.Log.Fatal(ex);
                                    return;
                                }
        }

public class CronJob : IJob
    {
public Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
            ServiceLogger.Log.Debug("Trigger");
            
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
}

As a result, I should get a service that works according to the CRON expression. But in no case do I get a response, even in such a simple case.
